# How to server static web page with webapp on GAE

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, web-applications

i like to know how to serve a static HTML page by GAE using webapp framework. using python , the api states

```
self.response.out.write(htmlcontent)
```

is there any way to just provide the html filename, and GAE automatically servers it? Or do I have to manually load the file and put the contents using the above function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can serve a static HTML page like this, in `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /
  static_files: main.html
  upload: main\.html
```

This will serve the file `main.html` on the root (`/`)  of the app.